# How to deal with NA when using lappy in R

Tags: r, if-statement, na

I have a data frame `err` consisting of 796 rows and 54432 columns

I have to check the columns that have values not exceeding 20 and -20.

This is my approach:

```
do.call(cbind, (lapply(err, function(x) if((all(x<20)  & all(x>-20))) return(x) )))
```

I Have NA values in all of the columns and after i got

```
Error in if ((all(x < 20) & all(x > -20))) return(x) :
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I update the command using `!is.na` as:

```
 do.call(cbind, (lapply(err, function(x) if(!is.na(all(x<20)  & all(x>-20))) return(x) )))
```

But in this case all the columns are reported and the filter does not work.

Any help?

Comment: how about `min` & `max` where you can use `na.rm=T`

Comment: @mts, you should post an answer, seems a great option

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar lapply can also take a dataframe. The `l` refers to the return type

Comment: Why not just add a `!is.na(x) `  to the conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I don't have an example df check if this works for you:

```
do.call("cbind", lapply(err, function(x) if(min(x, na.rm=T) > -20  & max(x, na.rm=T) < 20) return(x) ))
```

Comment: you'll probably need to put -20 in between brackets to avoid the confusion with the assignment character (<-) and it's probably the other way around (max < 20 and min >(-20) )

Comment: @CathG Right. I made an edit. A blank space works too.

Comment: @nicola, right, as long as the < and - are not next to each other. I'll edit for the "other way around" problem...

Answer (score 1):

Using `apply`

```
err[apply(err, 2, function(x) min(x,na.rm=T) > -20 & max(x,na.rm=T) < 20)]
```